# How can I fix Docker errors when changing data-root

Tags: docker, permissions

I am looking for a solution when changing the data-root directory for Docker.

OS is Ubuntu 18.04.5.
Docker version is 20.10.1.

Without changes docker works fine, but I need to change the data-root to get more space.
I found two possible solutions:

1. Setting a symlink to /var/lib/docker
2. Creating /etc/docker/daemon.json with 'data-root' value set (including service restart and daemon-reload)

Both solutions do not work and throw the same errors. E.g. when I run

```
docker run hello-world
```

I get the error
*"Error response from daemon: symlink /proc/mounts /mnt/docker/aufs/mnt/[...]-init/etc/mtab: function not implemented"*

For

```
docker run mysql
```

I get
*"docker:failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): symlink hostname /bin/dnsdomainname: function not implemented"*

I have setup the mounted device in /etc/fstab with

```
UUID=<uuid>    /mnt    auto    auto,user,rw    0 0
```

which works fine so far for data storage. Errors occur only for docker.

Could this be a problem with permissions on the disk?

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem on my end and ended up formatting the external storage as ext4. mkfs.ext4 /dev/mmcblk0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).